# JavaScript performance forms to sheet

Tags: javascript, forms, performance, for-loop, google-sheets

I have a problem that I just can't find the solution to.
It's about the performance of my script. I transmit data to my sheet via forms. I intercept this data with “onFormSubmit(e)” and split it into two other sheets according to conditions. If the answer “let out” is “OK”, then all matches with “Input” should be supplemented with “A-” in the specified columns.
The script when I run it with all 20 input numbers takes about 20 seconds for the transmission.
I would like to reduce this time by at least half. Do you have any tips for me on how I can implement this?

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  let lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  try {
    lock.waitLock(10000);
  } catch (e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("⚠️ Timeout", "Try again later!", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
    return;
  }

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const cpSheet = ss.getSheetByName('CP');
  const seSheet = ss.getSheetByName('SE');
  let out = "OK";
  let time = e.values[0];
  let email = e.values[1];
  let status = e.values[2];
  let info = e.values[23];
  
  let inputLen = e.values.filter(String).length-3;
    if (info) {
      let inputLen = inputLen - 1;
    }

    function getMultipleRowsData() {
      let data = [];
       for(let i =0, len = inputLen; i < len; i++) {
          let input = e.values[3+i];
            data.push([time, email, status, input, info]);
       }
      return data;
    }

 let data = getMultipleRowsData();
  if (status == out) {
    let lastRow1 = cpSheet.getLastRow();
    cpSheet.getRange(lastRow1 + 1,1,data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  } else {
    let lastRow2 = seSheet.getLastRow();
    seSheet.getRange(lastRow2 + 1,1,data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  } 
}
```

The forms sheet looks like this:

time | email | status | input1 | input2 | input3 | ... | input20 | info

I hope anybody can help me.

Comment: `The script when I run it with all 20 input numbers takes about 20 seconds for the transmission.` My test takes about 1 second. What else do you have running on this sheet?

Comment: Hello. There ist nothing else running script on my sheet. Did you test it with google forms as data-entrie?

Comment: Maybe it's also because I use the forms variables directly in the loop. I'll give it a try and pass the form variables to an array first. maybe this will work better... What do you think? Do you possibly see a weak point somewhere else in the script or a place where I can improve something?

Comment: Another question. What is the different between e.values and e.response.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse() to get the form-Data. Ist one way better than the other?

Comment: form variables to an array first does Not solve the problem: let input = [e.values[1], e.values[2],...]

[time, email, status, input[1+i], info]

Comment: There are two `event-triggered` triggers for when a user submits a form and each has different Event Objects. One is for [Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) if the form submits to a spreadsheet and this includes an object `events`. The other trigger is for [Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1) and this includes an object `response`. For the purposes of this question, they essentially have the same effect though, of course, the structure and binding of the scripts would be different.

Comment: `The script when I run it with all 20 input numbers takes about 20 seconds for the transmission.` Would you please show how you are calculating this. For example, your "live" script might include many `Logger` statements and these will slow down execution.

Comment: I have now found a way to speed up the script myself. It was slow because new lines had to be added when inserting the data. Now I always have 100 empty lines as a buffer into which the data can be transferred. This optimization reduced the execution time of the script to 8 seconds.

Do you have any other ideas on how I can further optimize the speed?

Is choosing the bow the best choice? Or would a foreach or while loop perhaps work better here?

I would be very happy about your help...

Comment: It shouldn’t matter, you are only processing one response consisting of between 1 and 20 data values. Detailed troubleshoot of _your_ code on _your_ system is something that only _you_ can do.